# Вернуть выборку из анонимного PLSQL блока в C#

Tags: c#, oracle, plsql

Получилось вернуть выборку из запроса SELECT, но вот хотелось бы вернуть отдельную таблицу, с которой в теле блока делали много разного. Что-то удаляли, например, после сложной обработки (какие-то строки). Сейчас код такой:

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;
....
private void btn_execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string oracleDbConnection = @"Data Source= (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = " + tb_ip.Text + ")(PORT = " + tb_port.Text + ")))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = " + tb_servname.Text + ")));"
                + @"User Id=" + tb_login.Text + ";Password=" + tb_pass.Text + ";";
            try
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = rtb_Query.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("return_cursor", OracleType.Cursor);
                cmd.Parameters["return_cursor"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                using (cmd.Connection = new OracleConnection(oracleDbConnection))
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    this.dgv_results.DataSource = dt;
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    this.dgv_results.DataSource = dt;
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv_results.Rows)
                    {
                        row.HeaderCell.Value = String.Format("{0}", row.Index + 1);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Loading is ended");
                }
            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

А сам запрос:

```
declare

begin
    open :return_cursor for
        SELECT * FROM CITIES WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE (to_char(CIT_ID), '[2,4,6,8,0]') AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE (to_char(CIT_ID), '[\D]');
end;
```

То есть, я вижу как в курсор подать select чего-нибудь, но не представляю как вернуть что-нибудь вроде:

```
FOR Cur_row in SELECT * FROM CITIES LOOP
    <преобразования>
    other_table.add (Cur_row.CIT_ID); -- ну да, тут дичь
END LOOP;
open :return_cursor for SELECT * FROM other_table;
```

При этом other_table нигде в базе не создавать как таблицу (пусть и с последующим удалением).

Comment: из блоков pl/sql выборку вернуть невозможно. (кроме как через временные таблицы)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если требуемое в цикле преобразование возможно сделать внутри простого селекта - лучше сделать именно внутри селекта. А если нет, то вам может помочь `pipelined` функция. Она работает практически так, как вы просите, только вместо строки

```
other_table.add (Cur_row.CIT_ID); -- ну да, тут дичь
```

Нужно будет написать `pipe row` и добавить кое-что еще.

Теперь по шагам:

1. Создаете тип, который будет задавать строку запроса:

   ```
   create type city_row as object (
     city_id number,
     city_name varchar2(100));
   ```
2. На его основе создаете табличный тип:

   ```
   create type t_city_table as table of city_row;
   ```
3. Теперь создаете функцию, которая возвращает табличный тип:

   ```
   create or replace function get_cities return t_city_table pipelined as 
     cur_row city_row := city_row(null, null);
   begin
     FOR i in (SELECT * FROM CITIES) LOOP
         cur_row.city_id := i.city_id;
         cur_row.city_name := i.city_name; 
         --<преобразования>
         pipe row (cur_row); -- ваша "не дичь"
     END LOOP;
   end;
   /
   ```
4. Обращаетесь с ней, как с таблицей (почти):

   ```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE(get_cities);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте коллекцию.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE other_row AS OBJECT( CIT_ID NUMBER );
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE other_table AS TABLE OF other_row ;
/
```

и тогда ваш код скорее всего отработает:

```
FOR Cur_row in SELECT * FROM CITIES LOOP
    <преобразования>
    other_table.add (Cur_row.CIT_ID); -- ну да, тут дичь
END LOOP;
open :return_cursor for SELECT * FROM TABLE(other_table);
```