# Ошибка при вызове функции: ORA-22905 невозможно получить доступ к строкам элемента, не являющегося вложенной таблицей

Tags: sql, oracle, select, vba, plsql

Хочу вызвать функцию таким образом:

```
select * from table(sql4sst_cntr_eq_excel(iDept => '11',fStd => '27.01.2019 
21:00',fEnd =>'28.01.2019 21:00'))
```

> ORA-22905 невозможно получить доступ к строкам элемента, не являющегося вложенной таблицей

Почему выдает ошибку? Или посоветуйте, как лучше передать функцию в Excel VBA?

Сама функция:

```
create or replace function sql4sst_cntr_eq_excel(iDept int,
                      fStd  varchar2, 
                      fEnd  varchar2,
                      t     varchar2 default 'n' -- 'y'
                      ) return varchar2 is
```

Нужно мне это для вызова в VBA:

```
Sub loadVal()
With ActiveSheet
Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection

Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Connection.ConnectionString = connstr
Connection.Open
Dim sSql As String, sDept As String, sDate As String, eDate As String, 
sFormatD As String
sDept = Range("Q1").Value
sDate = Range("F2").Value
sFormatD = Range("G7").NumberFormat
eDate = Range("I2").Value
sSql = "select * " + _
" from TABLE(sql4sst_cntr_eq_excel(idept => '" + sDept + "', fstd => '" + 
sDate + "',fend => '" + eDate + "'))"

Dim r As ADODB.Recordset
Set r = Connection.Execute(sSql)
Range("ValC").Offset(1, 0).Value = ""
 Cells(1, 1).Value = "tst"
 Cells(2, 1).Value = "id_eq"
 Cells(3, 1).Value = "n_sh"
 Cells(4, 1).Value = "val"
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
While Not r.EOF

 Cells(1, i).Value = r.Fields("tst")
 Cells(1, i).NumberFormat = "d/m/yyyy"
 Cells(2, i).Value = r.Fields("id_eq")
 Cells(3, i).Value = r.Fields("n_sh")
 Cells(4, i).NumberFormat = sFormatD
 Cells(4, i).Value = r.Fields("val")
 i = i + 1
 r.MoveNext
Wend
End With
Connection.Close
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: функция возвращать должна таблицу, а не варчар, тогда можно использовать ее в select * from table("вызов функции")

Comment: Вот, буквально на прошлой неделе было: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/936620/180398

Comment: Либо вызывайте так: select sql4sst_cntr_eq_excel(iDept => '11',fStd => '27.01.2019 21:00',fEnd =>'28.01.2019 21:00') from dual Так вы получите одиночное текстовое значение, которое вернула вам функция

Answer (score 2):

От функции `sql4sst_cntr_eq_excel` ожидается возврат результата из четырёх колонок в табличном виде. Создайте соответствующие типы данных:

```
create or replace type myrowT as object (
    tst date, id_eq varchar2 (8), n_sh  varchar2 (16), val number)
/
create or replace type myrowsT as table of myrowT
/
```

Теперь, декларация самой функции:

```
create or replace package pkg1 is
    function sql4sst_cntr_eq_excel (
        iDept int, fStd varchar2, fEnd varchar2, t varchar2 default 'n'
        ) return myrowsT pipelined;
end;
/
Package PKG1 compiled
```

Перенесите реализацию старой функци в новую с учётом типа возврата. Так будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

Если функция возвращает имя таблицы, из которой нужно получить значение, то в вашем случае проще вначале получить имя таблицы вызвав

```
sSql = select sql4sst_cntr_eq_excel(idept => '"' + sDept + '"',
                                    fstd => '"' + sDate + '"',
                                    fend => '"' + eDate + '"')
       as TableName from dual
```

а уже потом составлять и выполнять запрос с полученным именем таблицы.