# Как можно вывести таблицу из функции и в дальнейшем работать с ней?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Есть SQL команда:

```
SELECT id, parameter, value -- id и parameter -> INTEGER, value -> VARCHAR2
FROM t_table
WHERE 1=1;
```

Которая выдает много (~15) строк, которые должна возврашать функция.

После, я хотел бы обрабатывать результат в цикле. Мне надо, эти строки постепенно "скармливать" процедуре в цикле, которая отредактирует значения, исправит параметр, и скопирует в другую таблицу.

Как я могу так сделать?

PS Для среды используется DataGrip

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936490/194569

Comment: @Mike но там же какой-то C#

Comment: Вы оракловую часть смотрите. Тем более в ответах речь исключительно про Oracle. И да, это практически первое что нашлось сильно похожего. Еще можно в гугле поискать по запросу 'oracle табличные функции'

Comment: И кстати вы не написали в каком именно цикле, на каком языке вы хотите обрабатывать результат. Потому как если вдруг на pl/sql, то есть и другие решения с возвратом курсора из функции

Comment: @Mike ну, у меня не написано ни слова про другие языки.
Мне надо эти строки постепенно скармливать процедуре в цикле, которая отредачит значения, исправит параметр. и скопирует в другую таблицу.
Весь скрипт на oracle sql. Для среды используется DataGrip.

Comment: А надо ли что бы эти 15 строк получала одна функция, а использовала другая ? (по тексту вопроса сейчас выходит именно так). Если вдруг это все обрабатывается в пределах одной процедуры и вы спрашиваете просто про цикл по строкам из запроса то обратите внимание на строку `FOR i in (SELECT * FROM CITIES) LOOP` в том ответе на вопрос выше по ссылке - это как раз цикл по строкам запроса ...

Comment: @Mike спасибо огромное - это-то я и искал

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Мне надо эти строки постепенно скармливать процедуре в цикле

Не надо постепенно скармливать, никогда не вызывайте SQL запросы в цикле.

Сразу "скормите" всё что есть, как в этом воспроизводимом примере:

```sql
create table p1 as
    select rownum id, 'param '||rownum val
    from dual connect by level<=3
/
create table p2 as select * from p1 where 1=0
/
declare 
    type paramtab is table of p2%rowtype;
    params paramtab;

    function getParams return paramtab is
        ret paramtab;
    begin
        select rownum id, 'param '||rownum val bulk collect into ret 
        from p1;
        return ret;
    end;
    procedure procParams (params paramtab) is
        newparams paramtab := params;
    begin
        for i in 1..newparams.count loop 
            --## здесь обработка параметров
            newparams(i).val := newparams(i).val||'**'; 
        end loop;
        
        forall i in indices of newparams
            insert into p2 values (newparams(i).id, newparams(i).val);
    end;
begin
    procParams (getParams);
end; 
/
```

Который даст ожидаемый результат:

```sql
select * from p2
/ 
        ID VAL                                           
---------- ----------------------------------------------
         1 param 1**                                     
         2 param 2**                                     
         3 param 3**
```